# How to compare rownames with column values and add new variable to dataframe in R program

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compare rownames in one matrix (df2) with column values in another dataframe (df1).  after comparing i want to add the values of df2 to df1 in new column.

```
df1
ID  value  
A    12
B    13
C    14
A    15


df2
    LocationID
A    2
B    3
C    4

Finalresult
ID   Value   LocationID
A     12        2
B     13        3
C     14        4
A     15        2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll find you get much better responses if you provide some sample data and a clear and specific description of your problem.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Questions like this one are too vague to answer.

Comment: Dont be discouraged though. Please feel free to re-work your question as per @Justin's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `merge`. You can set  `by.y` to inspect the rownames, `by.x` to `ID`

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'ID', by.y = 'row.names')
  ID value LocationID
1  A    12          2
2  A    15          2
3  B    13          3
4  C    14          4
```